find $ker f$ for this function
We Define the  normed vector space of bounded sequences in $ \mathbb C$ as follow:
$$ l_\infty := \{ x={x_k} \subset \mathbb C \mid \sup \{ |x_k| : k \in \mathbb N \} < \infty \}$$
$$ \|x\|=\sup \{ |x_k| : k \in \mathbb N \} $$
Let $ f:l_ \infty \to \mathbb C $
$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x_k}{3^k} $$
$f$ is a linear function. I have to find $ker f$
I know that
$ker f = \{x\in l_\infty \mid f(x) =0\}=\{x\in l_\infty \mid \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x_k}{3^k}=0\} $
But I could not find it.
I see there are many elements of $ker f$ here. For example
$x=(1,-3,0,0,0,...) $
or
$x=(0,-3,9,0,0,...) $
But I can't find any way to write all of this elements.
Any help?

Not sure what you expect. $\ker f$ is infinite-dimensional: if you prescribe any$x_2,x_3,\ldots$ with $\sup|x_k|<\infty$, put $x_1=-3\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{x_k}{3^k}$ and then $x\in\ker f$.

I got it.  Thank you
